# How to limit database / console access for app collaborators in Heroku?

Tags: heroku

Heroku doesn't allow different collaborators to have different privileges, given there isn't an option for this in Dashboard -> YourAppName -> Collaborators.

I'm interested in restricting access to production database in a rails app- essentially removing console access. I'd still like collaborators to be able to push code and scale workers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - it's all or nothing I'm afraid.